# Google App Engine Index entires for ints and Longs

Tags: google-app-engine

We have an entity

```
    @Entity
     public class Cow
     {
          @Id      private Long cowID;
          @Index   private int age;
          @Index   private long geoLoc;
                   private cowStuff cowData;
      // getters, setters, etc
     }
```

Using objectify, we filter for a range of ages and a single geoLoc (since we can't have multiple inequality filters).  How many index entries are generated for each entity since the 2 indexes are int & long ?

Comment: The queries we run are of the form      results = ofy().load()
        .type(User.class)
  .filter("age >=", sb.getMinAge())
  .filter("age <=", sb.getMaxAge())
  .filter("geoLoc", sb.getGeoloc())
  .limit(maxSize)
  .list();

Answer (score 1):

Single property indexes and multiple property indexes are a little different.

Objectify uses @Id to create a single property index for those fields you annotated. Each field will result in one index entry (under the assumption that the type never changes - which in the case of Objectify is a safe assumption)

For some queries, appengine can leverage a combination of different single property indexes.
However, certain queries require a multiple property index - you can [read more about that here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_limits).

For multiple property indexes, you have to add them yourself manually in `datastore-indexes.xml`.

The dev server will prompt you when you need a multiple property index, and make a suggestion in the form of an xml snippet.

Comment: The page that got me thinking : [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/article/indexselection ) about large numbers of index entries

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the queries you run on your devserver.  If you don't run any queries in your dev server and just push this as is, it will create 3 different indexes (default one(ID), one for age, one for geoLoc)... maybe 3 (not sure how the App Engine handles custom properties as columns honestly).

If you run queries on your entity, it will create more indexes to be able to serve those queries.

You can look inside your "index.yaml" if you're in python, or inside "WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml" if you're in java, to see the index your devserver thinks you can use.

More info... for [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes)  or for [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig)